# npm package for Microsoft Windows Azure Ad, using Microsoft ADAL library underneath for Angular 6

Tags: typescript, azure-active-directory, angular6, adal

Does anyone has working [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) package which will provide authentication against Microsoft Windows Azure AD, using the Microsoft ADAL library underneath for Angular 6 and should generate token to call API?

I can use [ng2-adal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-adal) in angular 4 and is working as expected - Azure AD Authentication and generating token to call API.

But when i implemented same in angular 6 its not generating token. Azure AD Authentication is working but token generation is not working.

Its not returning anything from mergeMap call.

As per my knowledge mergeMap return the token in string in case of token observable. which is generated by adalservice.Acquiretoken method.

Comment: I use angular-oauth2-oidc in an Angular 6 application together with Azure AD. Is this an option for you?

Comment: no, i don't think so, looking at configuration of this package because it needs some more configuration values which i didn't have. I have Azure AD App client Id and App Id URI of Azure AD App of related API